# Regex file if array is not passed

Tags: php, json, regex

I have a file with this structure:

```
[19-02-2016 16:57:17.104504] [info] system done. 
 0: array(
   'ID' => 'john foo'
 )

[19-02-2016 16:57:17.110482] [info] transaction done. 
   0: array(
      'ID' => 'john foo'
   )
```

Now I want parse the file content as json, and actually all working well:

```
<?php
$file = 'test.log';

$content = array(); 
$content["trace"] = array();
$input = file_get_contents('test.log');

preg_match_all('/\[(.*)\][\s]*?\[(.*?)\][\s]*?(.*)[\s][^\']*\'ID\'[ ]*=>[ ]*\'(.*)\'/', $input, $regs, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($regs[0]); $i++) {
    $content['trace'][] = array(
        'date'    => $regs[1][$i],
        'type'    => trim($regs[2][$i]),
        'message' => trim($regs[3][$i]),
        'ID'      => trim($regs[4][$i]),
    );
}

// return $content;
echo '<pre>'; print_r($content); echo '</pre>';  // For testing only
$content = json_encode($content);                // For testing only
echo '<pre>' . $content . '</pre>';              // For testing only
```

now this code return this result:

```
{
"trace":[
    {
        "date":"19-02-2016 16:57:17.104504",
        "type":"info",
        "message":"system done.",
        "ID":"john foo"
    },
    {
        "date":"19-02-2016 16:57:17.110482",
        "type":"info",
        "message":"transaction done.",
        "ID":"john foo"
    }
]
```

}

the problem is that if I have for example this situation (in the file):

```
[19-02-2016 16:57:17.104504] [info] system done. 

[19-02-2016 16:57:17.110482] [info] transaction done. 
   0: array(
      'ID' => 'john foo'
   )
```

I get no result 'cause the regex fail. This is 'cause the first line doesn't have any array, how I can fix this situation?

**CODEHART CODE:**

```
preg_match_all('\[(.*)\][\s]*?\[(.*?)\][\s]*?(.*)[\s.]([^\']*\'ID\'[ ]*=>[ ]*\'(.*)\')?', $fh, $regs, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

        for($i = 0; $i < count($regs[0]); $i++)
        {
            var_dump($regs);
            $content['trace'][] = array(
                'date'    => $regs[1][$i],
                'type'    => trim($regs[2][$i]),
                'message' => trim($regs[3][$i]),
                'ID'      => trim($regs[4][$i]),
            );
        }
```

I get `null` from the var_dump

Comment: My initial thought is that you're going to have to change your logic to check each line for the date first as that's your marker for a new entry. Maybe split the file on `\r\n[` to break each entry into an array element. Then for each array element, parse the pieces you need.

Comment: Essentially the array is a trace log generated by an user, this help me to recognize the user on the system that have generated a transaction. Now if I don't pass any context the problem happean.

Comment: @Sandokan, you haven't added the starting and trailing `/`, Please update your code, although I will also confirm in a few minutes

Comment: @Sandokan, check the updated answer, now you won't have to update your for loop as well, just put in a relevant check for the Index number 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: the php code

```
  preg_match_all('/\[(.*)\][\s]*?\[(.*?)\][\s]*?(.*)[\s.]+(?:\d+[^\']*\'ID\'[ ]*=>[ ]*\'(.*)\')?/', $input, $regs, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Edit: Added the `array` part of the string to be optional and also notice the `\d`, have assumed that the array line will always start with a digit, so that it doesn't match the next line in the log as well, as was pointed out by @dillinger

Comment: uhm there is a bit problem I get from `$content` this: `array(1) {
  ["trace"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}`

Comment: Yes, I have just updated the regex, so you will have to change your `for` loop code as well, take a `print_r` of `$regs` and update your code

Comment: just to confirm, make sure you are using the string within the function like `preg_match_all('/\[(.*)\][\s]*?\[(.*?)\][\s]*?(.*)[\s.]([^\']*\'ID\'[ ]*=>[ ]*\'(.*)\')?/', .....)`

Comment: yes.. I also have update the question with your code but I still get null

Comment: Ok running it in php will confirm in a few minutes

Comment: @codeHeart I apologize for the intrusion, but I tried your code and it does not seem that it functions as it should, a little look: http://pastebin.com/NyfA1cTi 
As you see the file has a content with the initial array, one without, one with, and one without. It seems that the second line is coupled with the third ?! What happens here? I hope I have helped to fix in the expectation that the author sees the answer.

Comment: @Dillinger, Thanks for pointing out, another example of a programmer(me.. me) missing out on the edge cases :). Updated the answer

Comment: @codeHeart No problem, I found myself here because I have a pretty similar problem, maybe if you manage to solve here you can throw an eye to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35514205/match-uri-with-current-url/35514512#35514512